# Multilanguage website with jquery

Tags: jquery, multilingual

Hi I'm working on a old cms and I need to put all languages in `<span>` with a specicific class for every language:

```
<h1><span class="phps_lang phps_it">Titolo italiano pg2</span><span class="phps_lang phps_en">English title pg2</span></h1>
<p><span class="phps_lang phps_it">Testo italiano pg2</span><span class="phps_lang phps_en">English text pg2</span></p>
```

With jquery i make var for each span with specific class and I change text in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(sessionStorage.getItem("en") !="true") {
    $('.phps_it').each( function() { 
      cont_text_ita = $(this).parent();
      ita_text = $(this).text();

      $(cont_text_ita).text(ita_text);
    });

    $("#menu_lang li").not(".sel_it").removeClass("selected");
    $(".sel_it").addClass("selected");

} else {
    $('.phps_en').each( function() { 
      cont_text_eng = $(this).parent();
      eng_text = $(this).text();

      $(cont_text_eng).text(eng_text);
    }); 

    $("#menu_lang li").not(".sel_en").removeClass("selected");
    $(".sel_en").addClass("selected");
}

$(".sel_en a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#menu_lang li").not(".sel_en").removeClass("selected");
    $(".sel_en").addClass("selected");
    sessionStorage.setItem("en", true);
    location.reload();
});  
$(".sel_it a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#menu_lang li").not(".sel_it").removeClass("selected");
    $(".sel_it").addClass("selected");
    sessionStorage.setItem("en", false);
    location.reload();
});
```

});

Do you know if I can do this without reload page?
Do You think it's nasty for searching engines?

Here's a test:

[test pages](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/prova/prova1.html)

Comment: This is bad for search engines, but also people using screen readers or text browsers!

Comment: ok but so what can I do? I can't duplicate each page because there are too many pages to manage...
It can be better if i just hide the span with .hide(); ?

Comment: the standard is to get the selected language through the URL or a session variable, and on the server-side only output the correct language text.

It would be slightly better if you removed the non-matching language text, as most screen readers actually run JS, but I am not sure about search engine bots, they might still see both languages.

Comment: I know but in this case we have no server side, just static pages...

Comment: The Cms generate static pages this is why i've tried this solution...

Comment: Do you think that <!--googleoff: index--> <!--googleon: index--> can be helpful?